# How come my full circle isn't 360 degrees?

Tags: python, coordinates, angle, qgis

I am stuck with a confusing problem. Here's a little background:

I'm working on qgis/python with coordinate points in Lambert93: one central point (my dict key) and several other points gravitating around it. To simplify, the code I've put down just one example:

```
import numpy as np
import math

dict = {(355385,6.68906e+06): [(355277,6.68901e+06), (355501,6.68912e+06), (355364,6.6891e+06), (355277,6.68901e+06)]}

for key, values in dict.iteritems():
    anglist =[]
    print key
    i=0
    j=1
    for sides in values[:-1]:

        A = np.array(dict[key][i])
        B = np.array(key)
        C = np.array(dict[key][j])

        BA = A - B
        BC = C - B

        cosine_angle = np.vdot(BA, BC) / (np.linalg.norm(BA) * np.linalg.norm(BC))
        angle = (np.degrees(np.arccos(cosine_angle)))

        i+=1
        j+=1 

        anglist.append(angle)
        s = sum(anglist)
    dict[key]= [values, anglist, s] 
print dict
```

results are :

```
{(355385, 6689060.0): [[(355277, 6689010.0), (355501, 6689120.0), (355364, 6689100.0), (355277, 6689010.0)], [177.4925133253854, 90.349597027985112, 87.142916297400205], 354.98502665077069]}
```

As you can see, sum = 354. I have a large set of data and sometimes I get the correct 360, but for the most part I don't. Yet in all logic, by turning around a single point and ending the calculation where it started, the only result i should get is 360.

I have tried a second way just to see if the `cosine-angle` and `angle` weren't the problem :

```
from math import sqrt
from math import acos
import numpy
def angle(a, b, c):

    # Create vectors from points
    ba = [ aa-bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b) ]
    bc = [ cc-bb for cc,bb in zip(c,b) ]

# Normalize vector
    nba = sqrt ( sum ( (x**2.0 for x in ba) ) )
    ba = [ x/nba for x in ba ]

    nbc = sqrt ( sum ( (x**2.0 for x in bc) ) )
    bc = [ x/nbc for x in bc ]

# Calculate scalar from normalized vectors
    scale = sum ( (aa*bb for aa,bb in zip(ba,bc)) )

# calculate the angle in radian
    angle = numpy.degrees(acos(scale))
    return angle

print angle((355277,6.68901e+06),(355385,6.68906e+06), (355501,6.68912e+06))
print angle((355501,6.68912e+06),(355385,6.68906e+06), (355364,6.6891e+06))
print angle((355364,6.6891e+06),(355385,6.68906e+06), (355277,6.68901e+06))
```

But the results are still:

```
177.492513325
90.349597028
87.1429162974
```

So I think we can cross the math out of the problem... So one possibility is a problem with how qgis (or python?) manages the coordinates. How can I go around this?

I should say, the codes are largely the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551742/angle-between-three-points-in-python-why-this-result), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122372/angle-between-points) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551742/angle-between-three-points-in-python-why-this-result)

Comment: In the last example, you likely have one angle that is >180 degrees. The problem is, the standard branch of the `acos()` function is only able to return values out of [0, pi/2]. Most likely the first angle has to be 182.51 degrees - then the numbers sum up nicely. But I don't have time to verify the numbers now. To fix this, you need additional check logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hellmar's indication, here's the working code. I did two things : gave all the central points (0,0) in my plane, substracted the distance between the central point and (0,0) from all the other related points.
I was then able to use atan2 because all the angles I needed to calculate were at (0,0). Atan2 is very practical in this context because it only needs two points to calculate the angle : the angle measured is always the one at 0,0.
This probably means I don't have to set my central point as 0,0 as it just get kicked out of the equation.
Here's my code. Any further advice is much welcome.

```
import numpy as np
dictionary = {(355385,6.68906e+06): [(355277,6.68901e+06), (355501,6.68912e+06), (355364,6.6891e+06), (355277,6.68901e+06)], (355364,6.6891e+06): [(355261,6.68905e+06), (355385,6.68906e+06), (355481,6.68916e+06), (355340,6.68915e+06), (355261,6.68905e+06)], (355340,6.68915e+06): [(355238,6.68909e+06), (355364,6.6891e+06), (355452,6.68921e+06), (355238,6.68909e+06)]}
def angle_between(p1, p2):
    ang1 = np.arctan2(*p1[::-1])
    ang2 = np.arctan2(*p2[::-1])
    return np.rad2deg((ang1 - ang2) % (2 * np.pi))

zlist=[]
newdict={}
for key, values in dictionary.iteritems():
    xlist =[]
    ylist = []
    i=0
#print key
#print key[0]
    for sides in values:

        A = dictionary[key][i][0]
        B = key[0]
        C = dictionary[key][i][1]
        D= key[1]
        E = (0.0, 0.0)

        o1 = A-B
        o2  = C-D

        xlist.append(o1)
        ylist.append(o2)
        ziplist = zip(xlist, ylist)
        i+=1
    zlist.append(ziplist)  

#print dict[key][i][0]

newdict=zlist
print newdict
angledict = []

for p in newdict:
    i=0
    j=1
    print p
    for q in p[:-1]:
        A=p[i]
        B=p[j]
        print "A=",A
        print "B=", B

        angledict.append(angle_between(A,B))
        i+=1
        j+=1

print angledict
```

I took the angle_between function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735499/calculate-angle-clockwise-between-two-points)